# divs with pixel dimensions wrapping when they shouldn't

Tags: html, css

Given a structure like so:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-sidebar">
    <div class="item">some stuff 300px wide</div>
    <div class="item">some stuff 300px wide</div>
    <div class="item">some stuff 300px wide</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And styles like so:

```
#container {
  width:1170px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#left-sidebar {
  width: 900px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  margin-right:30px;
  width:270px;
}
```

This should have 3 "items" across @ 300px each, yet the items wrap at 2 items. This is on Firefox 25. Why do they wrap even though technically they have the exact space required? Firebug is reporting all divs have the correct pixel widths.

In pure CSS and simple HTML it might work but this is a complicated site with many other elements/styles - although Firebug is reporting the element widths as 270px + 30px margin and 900px.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `float:right` then you must put the `#right-sidebar` first in the source :

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="right-sidebar">
  some more stuff
  </div>
  <div id="left-sidebar">
    <div class="item">some stuff 300px wide</div>
    <div class="item">some stuff 300px wide</div>
    <div class="item">some stuff 300px wide</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**See JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6zMk6/)

Comment: Actually the right-sidebar has no effect and the problem exists without it, have updated the question.

Comment: Sorry I cannot replicate the problem on Firefox. Can you put your exact code on jsfiddle.net and I'll give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this a classic white-space-between-elements problem. I removed the whitespace and now the problem's gone.

Comment: I created a jsFiddle with your code and everything looked okay: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/wP7q8/  Because of the floats, the white space between the `div.item` should not be a problem.  If you had used `inline-blocks`, then your solution would make sense.  Something else must have been going on.